# NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for: NHibernateExperiment.Player - i can't find the solution

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I try to make a project with the NHibernate ORM, and at one moment when i thought that all I finished , it gives me an **NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for** exception
I read that the problem could be that i didn't added the assembly in config file, but I did this, and also it is not fixed...

If someone has a litle time, help me please to fix the problem.

here is **the code I call** to add a new Player object

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player playerData = new Player();
            SetPlayerInfo(playerData);

            using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession)
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        session.Save(playerData); // here it spits
                        transaction.Commit();
                        GetPlayerInfo();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

private void GetPlayerInfo()
        {
            using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession)
            {
                IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM Player");
                IList<Player> pInfos = query.List<Player>();
                dgvDisplay.DataSource = pInfos;
            }
        }

private void SetPlayerInfo(Player playerData)
        {
            playerData.PlayerName = tbxName.Text;
            playerData.PlayerAge = Convert.ToInt32(tbxAge.Text);
            playerData.DOJ = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpDOJ.Text);
            playerData.BelongsTo = cmbBelongsTo.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

here is the mapping **Player.hbm.xml** code

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true">
  <class name="NHibernateExperiment.Player, NHibernateExperiment" lazy="true">
    <id name="PlayerId">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="PlayerName" column ="PlayerName"/>
    <property name="PlayerAge" column ="PlayerAge"/>
    <property name="DOJ" column="DOJ"/>
    <property name="BelongsTo" column="BelongsTo"/>
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

here is the **App.config** code

```
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=GRITCAN;database=testDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>          
      <property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>          
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

here is the **StackTrace**

at NHibernateExperiment.Form1.btnInsert_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\projects\tests\NHibernate\NHibernateExperiment\NHibernateExperiment\Form1.cs:line 72 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) 
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData) at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm) 
at NHibernateExperiment.Program.Main() in E:\projects\tests\NHibernate\NHibernateExperiment\NHibernateExperiment\Program.cs:line 16 at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args) 
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() 
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

I've added the following 2 references to the project
**NHibernate.dll** and **NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll**

**Thanks a lot for your help!**

---

Thank You BOYS. 
The **Build Action** for **.hbm.xml** file was **Content**. 
As you suggested me I changed it to **Embedded Resource** and all works fine:)

Comment: Make sure to change the *Build Action* for `.hbm.xml` file to *Embedded Resource*.

Comment: Thank You. The **Build Action** for **.hbm.xml** file was **Content**. I changed it to **Embedded Resource** and all works fine:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if xml mapping is marked as embedded resource. Also I'd reccomend you to use Fluent nHibernate library - this is a freedom from writing huge amount of xml mappings, only .net clasess

Comment: You don't need Fluent to replace xml. You could also use mapping by code, a NH feature since version 3.2.

Comment: Nice to know it - really cool feature. Sorry, I don't follow the latest changes and still use 1.X version

Answer (score 3):

Did you make the mapping file an embedded resource?

Comment: Thank You. The **Build Action** for **.hbm.xml** file was **Content**. I changed it to **Embedded Resource** and all works fine:)

Comment: it's not enough - check this file Build Action proferty. It should be embedded resource

Answer (score 0):

working Solution:

**Form1.cs**
    using NHibernate;
    using NHibernate.Cfg;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

```
namespace NHibernateTutorialPart1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private Configuration myConfiguration;
        private ISessionFactory mySessionFactory;
        private ISession mySession;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myConfiguration = new Configuration();
            myConfiguration.Configure("hibernate_mysql.cfg.xml");
            mySessionFactory = myConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
            mySession = mySessionFactory.OpenSession();

            using (mySession.BeginTransaction())
            {
                Contact lbContact=new Contact{FirstName="Nisha", LastName="Shrestha",ID=0};
                mySession.Save(lbContact);
                mySession.Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}

**hibernate_mysql.cfg.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      User Id=root;
      Server=localhost;
      Password=Password1;
      Database=nhibernatecontacts;
    </property>

    <!--This is good for Debugging but not otherwise-->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!--<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>-->
    <mapping assembly="NHibernateTutorialPart1"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>


**contact.hbm.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateTutorialPart1"
                   namespace="NHibernateTutorialPart1">
  <class name="Contact" table="contact">
    <id name="ID" column="ID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName" />
    <property name="LastName" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

**Contact class**


namespace NHibernateTutorialPart1
{
    public class Contact
    {

        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    }
}


**App.config**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler,NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>
</configuration>

You need to add reference for lesi.collection and NHibernate
You need to do embeded resource for contact.hbm.xml and hibernate_mysql.cfg.xml
```

I used mysql workbench where i created a new schema and new table with id, first name and last name.

The solution for No persister for exception was i forgot to gave table name in contact.hbm.xml